# Setting a value and selected attribute to an options tag

Tags: angular, html, angular6

Been trying to wrap my head around the issue of setting a value and a selected attribute to an options tag. Both work fine induvidually on the tag but neither works if the other is present.

Example:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" selected [ngValue]="item">
       {{item.value}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

In the example the "selected" tag will be ignored and only a value will be set.
If I remove the [ngValue] the selected attribute will be applied to the element.

How can I solve this, allowing me both to highlight a selected option as well as giving it a value?

Using Angular 6  & Typescript

Answer (score 0):

You have to create function which take this `item` like the parameter and return boolean - `isSelected(item)` for example. And result of this function will indicate whether `selected` should be true or false.
And `value` you can assign just like you show it so `[value]="item.value."`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited description you provided, seems like items is an array of objects. Try assigning the actual value to [ngValue], like [ngValue]=item.value. Based on your code, seems like you are tying to assign object to [ngValue] which might confuse template to parse the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `selected` in the way you have, every `<option>` is selected, and from there on it is chaos. It's not clear to me based on what you're selecting, so for my solution, I'm expecting a local variable with the value of the selected `<option>`:

```
selectedItem = "Three";
```

Then, bind to an expression evaluating this:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [selected]="selectedItem == item.value" [ngValue]="item.value" >
   {{item.value}}
</option>
```

Full StackBlitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6cxkf